# How to connect Google Glass to WPA 2 Enterprise?

Tags: google-glass

I study in a university where all of us have an id/password combination to use the internet. Is it possible to connect Google Glass to such an Enterprise WPA 2 network? If yes, how? And if no, is there a solution for this?

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can't connect to WPA2 Enterprise as of yet with Glass.  <strike>For now I'd submit a ticket to Google through their issue tracker if I were you.  [Glass Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list)</strike>

**EDIT:** Because WPA2 connection isn't a developer issue you should contact the Glass team here instead: [Glass Guide Team Support](https://support.google.com/glass/answer/3079854)

Comment: This isn't really a developer API feature, so the linked issue tracker is not the best. The best way to submit this request is to contact the Guide team: https://support.google.com/glass/answer/3079854

Comment: Ah, my bad.  Thanks for letting me know.  I'll update my answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to get this to work was to find a cheap router, connect it to the wired network, and then associate Glass with the router's network (which you have set up with WEP or WPA or nothing).

I have also used the "share my internet connection" feature in OS X to share an ethernet connection over AirPort.

...I hope someone chimes in with a better answer, but hopefully this might be enough to get you started?

Answer (score 0):

For a quick test, you could turn on Portable Wi-Fi hotspot on your smart phone and connect that way. This can only be a temporary measure really, because you can't simultaneously connect to your University Wi-Fi so you would have to use your own data. Not a permanent solution, but OK if you want to do a quick test.

On the other hand, there does seem to be a Glass app you can install [here](http://www.glassappsource.com/google-glass-how-to/connect-enterprise-wpa-network-google-glass.html) as a work around.

Another alternative is to check if your University has a "guest" network, which is usually a standard connection (i.e. not Enterprise)